# MongoDB v5.0.5 query using hour only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

First occasion experimenting with dates and times in MongoDB.

Currently, I have correctly inserted UTC dates into my documents:

```
{
 "Value": 10
 "DateTime": {
        "$date": "2013-08-23T08:00:00.000Z"
    },
}
```

I want to query the data to return all of the 'value' and datetime fields for all documents in which the hour is 08. I have gotten as far as:

```
db.readings.aggregate([{$project:{hour:{$hour:"$DateTime"}}},{$match:{hour:{"$in":[08]}}}])
```

Which returns the `_id` and `"hour": 8` for all matching entries but I'm confused at how to proceed. It seems an unnecessarily complicated way to search and so I wonder if I am barking up the wrong tree here? Admittedly, I am somewhat out of my depth so some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `$expr` expression operator to use aggregation operators (`$hour`) in query,

- `$expr` to use aggregation operators
- `$hour` will return an hour from the date
- `$eq` to match hour and input hour 8

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      { $hour: "$DateTime" },
      8
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1pHfyd6oSuV)